# Seaborn - heatmap setting frequency of DateTime ytick labels

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, seaborn

I have the following heatmap that I'm working on. I want to adjust the Y-axis tick labels so that they show up only every 8 or 12 hours but couldn't make it work.

Shouldn't this be possible with HourLocator?

If I use the following `ax.yaxis.set_major_locator(md.HourLocator(interval=24))` the Y tick labels disappear.

Data Frame looks as follows:

```
                     name            values_1   values_2    rate
date_time               
2022-06-03 17:00:00   A              115    45      0.718750
2022-06-03 17:00:00   B              713    2617    0.214114
2022-06-03 17:00:00   C              43     577     0.069355
2022-06-03 17:00:00   D              60     62      0.491803
2022-06-03 17:00:00   E              321    1027    0.238131
......
```

[image]

```
sns.set(rc={'figure.figsize':(12,8)})
ax = sns.heatmap(df_new.pivot_table(values='rate',index='date_time', columns='name'));
ax.yaxis.set_major_locator(md.HourLocator(interval=24))
```

On the Y-axis I have the index in Pandas date time and on the X-axis, I have the name.

Answer (score 0):

I found that in the documentation it's possible to set the frequency via `xticklabels` https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.heatmap.html

> If an integer, use the column names but plot only every n label."